# Framework Blackboxing while using Webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack

Is it possible to Blackbox certain parts of a WebPack bundle so that Chrome does not show the stack trace of Framework internals? For example, when examining an error on a React app, I don't care about stack trace entries inside of the framework, rather I just want to see the parts that relate to code I wrote.

This is possible with "Framework Blackboxing" when using single files, but I don't know how to accomplish it with a WebPack bundle.

Comment: https://denysdovhan.com/blackboxing-react/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `devtool: "#eval"` in your Webpack config (or `--devtool #eval` on the command line) seems to support both black-boxing and proper stack traces.

Comment: It breaks my ES6 code (weird `_this` and so on), but it's better than nothing. Anyone knows how to save ES6 source but still skip blackboxed scripts?

Comment: Blackboxing with SourceMaps is [not supported yet](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=583193) but will be available.